# Spring Boot 2.6.6 Failed to create asynch executor instance : Failed to instantiate [java.util.concurrent.Executor]: Illegal arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor

I am upgrading Spring Boot version from 2.4.6 to 2.6.6

After upgrade, one of the class failed to load and giving an error like below:

> Failed to instantiate [java.util.concurrent.Executor]: Illegal
> arguments to factory method 'threadPoolTaskExecutor'; args: ; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an
> instance of declaring class

It failed to create a instance of executor service class.

This is the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ApplicationAsynchConfig  implements AsyncConfigurer{
    
    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        //set some properties
        return executor;
    }
  }
```

Any idea what is going wrong with the new Spring Boot version for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the approach to solve the issue but after the changes the application started and working as expected.

The solution is to remove the `AsyncConfigurer`

Here is the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ApplicationAsynchConfig {
    
    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        //set some properties
        return executor;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in answers. I have removed the follow-up question. If you want to ask a follow-up question, ask a new question.